# TryParseExact not working with japan format

Tags: c#, .net, tryparse

I use TryParseExact to get date time from a string but it did not work.
My string is

`2019年01月24日 19:16`

I tried `CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");`, but it did not work too.

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(try_parse_string, "yyyy年MM月dd日 hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out action_time))
            {
                //do something
            }
            else
            {
                //do something
            }
```

Please tell me how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: `hh` -> `HH`. Have you tried searching?

Comment: @CodeCaster It is right. I found an example on internet in Microsoft document with `hh`. Have no idea why it is wrong. Any way. Thank you very very very much.

Comment: I knows the reason now. Thank you.